# OSX top command shows 5 running on a quad core

Tags: osx, top

When trying to run the top command on my quad core mac, I see periodically that there are 5 running processes. How could it be possible to have 5 running processes on a quad core machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's explained in the [`top`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top) man page:

> Tasks shown as running should be more properly thought of as 'ready to run' – their `task_struct` is simply represented on the Linux run-queue.  Even without a true SMP machine, you may see numerous tasks in this state depending on top's delay interval and nice value.